# StringBuilder add Separator between appended Strings

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `StringBuilder` for logging errors and messages conveniently, and its instance will be pass around methods. My goal is to append errors together, separated by comma, such as `"Duplicated ID, Invalid cost, Unsupported Service for account"`. However, I couldn't find any supported [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=netframework-4.7.2)  that separates each appended string with a separator, such as:

```cs
//Maybe something like a default separator?
errorBuilder.DefaultSeparator=',';
errorBuilder.Append("Duplicated ID");
errorBuilder.Append("Invalid cost");
errorBuilder.Append("Unsupported Service for account");
Log(errorBuilder.ToString())
```

`errorBuilder.Append(validateID(id) + ", ")` isn't ideal since it requires extra effort to remove the comma anywhere before `errorBuilder.ToString()` is called.

I am aware that I could just pass a List around and use `String.Join(",", "List.ToArray()")` or `StringBuilder.AppendJoin` or create a custom class, but I wonder if I can use the native [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) to achieve this goal?

I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Note: I would be Appending different messages or errors at different places, based on different scenarios and input, as a normal Error Tracer would.

Comment: I want to use the native StringBuilder because it is already been passed around many methods, changing it requires some effort. Also, to me `errorBuilder.ToString()` does looks cleaner than `String.Join(",", "List.ToArray()")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no functionality in `StringBuilder` that will make `Append` automatically put a comma between elements that you append.

> I want to use the native StringBuilder because it is already been passed around many methods, changing it requires some effort.

It sounds like your code got tightly coupled to the wrong abstraction. Fixing the problem will probably require some effort, but it's better to do it now than to continue using the wrong model.

Comment: I do agree it should be fixed. In this case I will probably choose to build my own class using StringBuilder under the hood, since I do worry about the performance since the data could be massive.

Comment: That code is reallllly tightly coupled since during the whole data processing process a write or read to the stringbuilder can happen, which is pretty much the whole program lol.

Comment: @SyndRain Consider separating responsibilities a little more. Maybe most of the program should really only be adding values to a collection or a POCO--no special class required. Then, at the end, you pass that collection to a renderer which turns it into a string. Whether that renderer uses StringBuilder, string.Join, or a Razor template it kept completely separate from the code that's populating the model object in the first place.